# Show that there is a $c$, such that $f'(c)=0$

Tags: integration, analysis, functions, derivatives

Given that $f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous and differentiable function satisfying

$$\int_a^b x^2f(x)dx ≠ \left(\frac{b ^ 3}{3} - \frac{a ^ 3}{3}\right)\cdot f(c) $$

for any $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$, show that ∃ c so that $f'(c)=0$.

I was thinking to take the expression and make it $> 0$ and then, in the second case $< 0$, resulting that $$\int_a^b x^2(f(x)-f(c))dx ≠0, $$ but I'm stuck here. Can you give me any idea to continue?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please, format your question using MathJax and take a look at [this tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) of the website. Generally, questions of the kind “here’s my question, please solve it” aren’t very well received.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type the math in your questions. Consider that many users won't even read your questions if they are not properly formatted, let alone help you.

Comment: @jjagmath i'm sorry, i hope it's ok now

Comment: Is your hypothesis $\forall a,b\color{red}\exists c\in\Bbb R\dots$ (or $\in[a,b]$)? Is the consequence to be proved $\color{red}\exists c\dots$ (like in the title)? If so, please say it in your post.

Comment: thanks, i edited.

Comment: It is still unclear to me. Do you mean $\int_a^b x^2f(x)dx ≠ \left(\frac{b ^ 3}{3} - \frac{a ^ 3}{3}\right)\cdot f(c)$ for all $a, b, c \in \Bbb R$? But for $a=b$ both sides are zero.  – Where does the problem come from? Is that the exact formulation or your interpretation of some other problem?

Comment: @MartinR, for any a,b real numbers, it exists a number c, real, so that \int_a^b x^2f(x)dx ≠ \left(\frac{b ^ 3}{3} - \frac{a ^ 3}{3}\right)\cdot f(c)

Comment: If a=b, the left side is always equal to the right side.

Answer (score -3):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQyHX.jpg)
this question wants to tell you extrema can't be he Mean Value Theorem for Integrals

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand the last part of your demonstration, it doesn't make sense to me

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos can you answer my question, please? I just don't know what to do...

Comment: @julia Why are you asking me?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I thought you would know the answer or you could give me an idea to start from